# Save Image to Gallery From image View

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save image to Gallery from image View but getting File Not Found Exception Error

The code I tried but got File Not Found Exception.

Sorry if you didn't understand my English.

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override

                public void onClick(View v){

                    BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable) mainImage.getDrawable();

                    Bitmap bitmap = draw.getBitmap();

                    try{

                        FileOutputStream outStream = null;

                        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                        File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFolder");

                        dir.mkdirs();

                        String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());

                        File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);

                        outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);

                        outStream.flush();

                        outStream.close();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);

                        intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(outFile));

                        sendBroadcast(intent);

                    }

                    catch (Exception e){

                        e.printStackTrace();

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    

                }

        });
```

I am a beginner so I don't how to solve this Problem.
Help me Please

Comment: Can you try other environments besides getExternalStorageDirectory?

Comment: I  am a beginner so tell me how I can try other environments

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#public-methods_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So let's start from scratch**

**Step 1:**
Add the permissions of Read and Write in your manifest

**Step 2:**
Make the Bitmap of the Image you have in ImageView

**Step 3:**
Now there is a different mechanism for saving files in the below and above Android Version Q

**In Below Q:**

```
private File saveBitmapBelowQ(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {
        File imageRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), appDirectoryName);
        if (!imageRoot.exists()) {
            imageRoot.mkdirs();
        }
        File image = new File(imageRoot, name + ".png");
        try {
            if (image.createNewFile()) {
                try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(image)) {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,
                            100, bos);
                    byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
                    fos.write(bitmapdata);
                    fos.flush();
                    imagePath = image.getPath();
                }
                return image;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  null;
    }
```

Where AppDirectory is the Name of the Directory you want and the name is the name of the Image preferred to use live date and time.
In this method,

1. First, create the Directory in External Storage.
2. Then create the file of your image (Try to make it unique)
3. The last step is to convert your Bitmap into a byte Array and write
   on the file you created in (point 2)

**In Android Version Q and Above:**

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    public File saveBitmapAboveQ(Bitmap bitmap, Context context, String directoryName, String name) {
        OutputStream fos;
        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/" + directoryName);
        Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
        try {
            fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            imagePath = new File(getPath(imageUri)).getAbsolutePath();
            return new File(getPath(imageUri));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Create a Content Resolver and set the content values such as File name, type, and location then pass content values to the content resolver and pass your content resolver to FileOutputStream/ OutputStream
Now write your Bitmap over the output stream

Happy Coding

Comment: Your code is working without allowing storage read and write permission. Can you explain me how is this working?

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin way:
You can use this extension function to save file in storage

```
fun Bitmap.saveAsFile(isPng: Boolean = false): File? {
    val root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    val myDir = File("${root}/pic")
    myDir.mkdirs()
    if (myDir.exists()) {
        val random = (Math.random() * (1024 - 1)).toLong()
        val prefix = "IMG${random}_${System.currentTimeMillis()}"

        val fileName = if (isPng) "$prefix.png" else "$prefix.jpg"
        val file = File(myDir, fileName)
    if (file.exists()) file.delete()
        return try {
            val out = FileOutputStream(file)
            if (isPng) {
                this.setHasAlpha(true)
                this.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out)
            } else {
                this.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out)
            }
            out.flush()
            out.close()
            file
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }
  return null
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
 val imageFile = view.drawToBitmap().saveAsFile()
```

Java way:

```
public static File saveAsFile(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/pic");
    if (myDir.mkdir()) {
        long random = (long) (Math.random() * (1024 - 1));
        String prefix = ("IMG" + random + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis());

        String fileName = prefix + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fileName);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            return file;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static Bitmap drawToBitmap(View view) {
    if (!ViewCompat.isLaidOut(view)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("View needs to be laid out before calling drawToBitmap()");
    }
    Bitmap bit = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bit);
    canvas.translate(-view.getScrollX(), -view.getScrollY());
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bit;
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = drawToBitmap(yourView);
    File savedFile = saveAsFile(bitmap);
```

Comment: I don't have knowledge about kotlin and how to use kotlin with java

Comment: i'm update code and add java way. u can check it.

Comment: Thanks, but I already got the Solution.

Comment: Great . you can update your question and add your solution to help other developers.